# new to javascript have a question about web front end

Tags: javascript, frontend

Write a function named "additionCalculator" that that doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return a value. This function will control the logic for a web-based calculator that adds two numbers (You can make more complex calculators this way, but we'll only add numbers for now so we can focus on the concept). There will be two text boxes on the web page with ids of "input_one" and "input_two" and an empty div with an id of "sum". Read the values of the two text boxes and write the addition of these two values inside the div. Note that every value you read from the page will be a string and you'll need to convert them to Numbers to perform the addition.

my code so far:

```
    function additionCalculator(){
        var one=document.getElementById("input_one").value;
        var two=document.getElementById("input_two").value;
        var my_js_variable = one + two;
        document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = my_js_variable;


    }

this is the output:

html: "<html>
<head>
<script src="myCode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sum">2-88</div>
<input type="text" id="input_one" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="input_two" value="-88"/>
<button onclick="additionCalculator();">Add</button>
</body>
</html>"
expected: "<html>
<head>
<script src="myCode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sum">-86</div>
<input type="text" id="input_one" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="input_two" value="-88"/>
<button onclick="additionCalculator();">Add</button>
</body>
</html>"
```

how can i make it so it adds the values from the first two inputs? thanks.

edit:

solved the answer due to help from below thank you!!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, what is the problem so far?

Comment: so with my code, the output is giving me 2-88, i want it to give me just -86(note the values are random there is no given value the professor already has inputted values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parseInt on your values from HTML, otherwise it'll be considered as string and concatenated as string
 
`var my_js_variable = parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);`